# 'Permission Denied' when getting images on S3 from Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a grails 2.1.1 app that is accessing images stored in a bucket on s3, which I am accessing using the Grails-AWS plugin.

Everything works fine when I use "grails run-app" and the server is localhost:8080/myApp.  I can put and get files with no problem.

But when I deploy the war file to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk I get the following error when trying to get an image:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: 90916.png (Permission denied)

at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)

at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)

at com.sommelier.domain.core.MyDomainObject.getPicture(MyDomainObject.groovy:145)
```

Here is my code for getting the image that is initiating the error:

```
    File getPicture() {

    def url = aws.s3().on("mybucket").url(image, "myfoldername")

    File imageFile = new File(image)
    def fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile)
    def out = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream)
    out << new URL(url).openStream()
    out.close()

    return imageFile        

}
```

I have set the permissions on my s3 bucket as wide open as I can. I have used the "Add more permissions" button and added every possible option.

Here is my bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1355414697022",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    }
]
 }
```

And my CORS configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

Any thoughts?  Is this a S3 permissions problem, or is there something else?

Comment: I think this linke: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=205071 may be helpful. Just not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to create the file where you don't have write permission.

It's better practice to not save a copy to the app server. If you can I suggest you return the manipulation/content/whatever from the object in memory.

But if you really do need the file locally for some reason, you should have write permission in /tmp

Comment: You're right on both counts.  The problem was not permissions with S3, but with my local file system. Also you are right that I did not need to write anything.  My new getPicture method now looks like this:  Image getPicture() {
  
  def url = aws.s3().on("mybucket").url(image, "myfolder")

  
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);

 }  Thanks for the help!